# For loops with promises

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to write three for loops with promises something like this:

```
for i = 1 .. 3
 for j = 1 .. 5
  for k = 1 .. 6
   post call to db to check if there is item on location i, j, k
```

- step 1: check 1,1,1
- step 2: check 1,1,2 item is found or inc next index
- ...

I searched for similar questions but I get only one-dimensional array loops examples.

I found this very hard problem and I hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: not only is this so vague it can't be reasonably answered, it is also misguided.  Promises are async, for loops are not.  you can't just "wait" for a promise to resolve.

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Claise: yes I used wrong words here, sry. jfriend00 explained in answers below what my problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

piping promises can be done linearly. So in your case, you have to first generate an array which holds all possible combinaisons like so:

```
$locations = [
    [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4],
    ....  
];
```

Then you can easily loop over this array and pipe your promises. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine a synchronous `for` loop with asynchronous operations and get things to sequence properly because there's no way to make a `for` loop "wait" for a promise to finish.  The `for` loop runs synchronously so it will just start all the async operations at once.

So, instead you have to do your iterations another way.  If you were iterating just one parameter, there would be a number of ready-made ways to do that, but I'm not aware of any pre-built solutions for iterating three nested variables so you will have to build your own.  Here's one way to do it.  This method is custom coded for your iterations which makes it a bit less code that a general scheme:

```
// fn gets called like this fn(i, j, k) and must return a promise
function iterateLevels(fn) {
    var i = 1, iMax = 3;
    var j = 1, jMax = 5;
    var k = 1, kMax = 6;

    function next() {
        if (k > kMax) {
            j++;
            k = 1;
        }
        if (j > jMax) {
            i++;
            j = 1;
        }
        if (i > iMax) {
            return;
        }
        return fn(i, j, k).then(function(result) {
            k++;
            // process result here

            // if you want to continue processing, then
            return next();
        });
    }
    return next();
}
```

Here's a working demo implementation using a promise with a random delay: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q2Lnhszt/

The `next()` function with the outer scope variables `i`, `j` and `k` is essentially a state machine where each time you call `next()` it runs the next iteration and updates its state.

This could be made generic so you pass in how many levels of iteration and what the start and stop values for each level are and you could pass in a function for processing the result.  Making it generic adds more code to the implementation and makes the logic a little harder to follow.